# Irregularity in my rendered image

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering

Close to a final result but not yet ... I have this irregularity in my rendered image (left bottom corner).

[image]

I guess it is caused by a small irregularity in my mesh ??

[image]

Is this correct ? And how best to solve such issues ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is a red spot in the image you are using as environment (it seems a red "camera" led)... :) it is just reflected by your glossy phone model.

Comment: Thx. I really thought it was caused by a modelling mistake.